# How can you send HTTP request through one server to another?

Tags: java, http, networking

I am working on a project and have run into an interesting problem. I have many different computers running on my network that don't have a public IP that I need to make http requests from. I do have a server that I have been using as a router that I can access via WAN. What would be the best way to forward http requests through java and handle responses as well? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You're either looking for a NAT or a proxy.

Comment: The normal approach to this is to set up e.g. nginx as a reverse proxy - this is offtopic here though.

Comment: What you would like to do is called Proxy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451413/java-http-proxy-server

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others this is probably off-topic but to keep it short you will need a proxy. In this case a reverse proxy (from the "Outside" to the "inside").

Your end computers won't have a public IP but private IP so they won't be accessible from the internet as the private IPs are not routed through the internet.
Thus you will need one device that has a public IP which you do have. 
On this server use a reverse proxy, either haproxy, nginx or a Java if it exists (or if you want to make it).

The steps are easy:
_ Listen to connection on port 80 and on the external interface
_ DNAT (destination NAT) those connections and send them to the computer(s)
_ Your proxy will have a session table keeping track of those connection.
_ On your workstation, you will need a default gateway: this will be your proxy as the workstation needs to know where to send the packet (random public IP).
_ Of course we assume that the workstations and the proxy are on the same network subnet. If not you will need another router to route the traffic in your LAN Area.

Hope this help.